# Adding custom actions to facebook comment plugin

Tags: facebook, comments

I am currently using the normal facebook comments plugin as such:

```
<p class="fb-comments"></p>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=API_ID&amp;xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:comments href="URL_OF_PAGE" num_posts="10" style="max-width:480px" width="300"></fb:comments>
```

I have a custom login section. but I want to be able to see who posts a comment on the website if they are logged in.

In other words this is exactly what I want to accomplish.

1. if the user is logged in, and they post a comment, I want to be able to store the ID (or username, email, etc) of the user thats logged in - into my DB.
2. if they are not logged in then i dont care to track it.

---

any one have any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Subscribe to the comment.create](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) method in javascript and then the check values in the response variable.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(response);
});
```

Comment: ah. i see what your saying. but instead of auth.sessionChange, i could use comment.create  and if i get a response, i can use that to trigger my insert into my table.   I am just not adding the same data as the comment. i dont care what they comment. I need to add their user ID (from my DB), timestamp and some custom info in my DB since i added 'points' to my site. so I want to give the user 'points' for posting a comment but i use FB comment so thats what im trying to figure out.

Comment: sorry i meant comment.create, copy and paste problem. I updated it. But yes, look at the response and if it was successful you could give the user points.

Comment: thanks bkaid. I havent written anything yet. I came to see if it was possible first.

Comment: that totally worked!!!! thanks man. all i had to do was throw a $post inside that fb function and check to see if the user is logged in my website. thanks again!  now to see if i could do that from a 'like' button and 'tweet' button.